# Nav bar looks wrong in IE 8 with Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

Ok I'm appologizing up front it there has been a similar question where there has, and I've tried everything so far that I have read!  Maybe there is something else I'm missing.  This will be my first live Bootstrap site.  I have a few pages on a testing domain.

It seems to be looking great in all modern browsers, my problem is IE (of course), it looks fine in ie 9 but the nav bar looks well, terrible in IE 8, (I don't care about ie7!)  I would at least like it to look OK in IE 8.

Based on other blog posts I HAVE already included the following into source code head  of my site to help in the rendering of older versions of IE:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the testing site URL:  www.amystout.com/meridian/irrigation.html

Here is how the nav bar is 'wrongly' getting displayed in IE 8,

[image: IE nav bar example]

[Flickr page](http://www.flickr.com/photos/asbilly92/16512038854)

Here's the code for that page:

```js
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-19558625-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function () {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #C4C0BF;
    background-image:url(../images/background_light_slice.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x
}
.glow {
    background-image:url(../images/background_light.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#logo-box img {
    border:none;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.slogan {
    float:right;
    margin-top: 75px;
}
.starter-template {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #C4C0BF;
}
.float-right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
}
img {
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
}
.float-left {
    float: left;
}
.align-right {
    text-align:right;
}
.container-wrap {
}
.nav-wrap {
    border-top:1px solid #dedede;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dedede;
    background-color:#333333;
}
nav.navbar.navbar-default {
    background-color:#333333;
    border:none;
}
.navbar {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color:#efeeee;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #b8b6b6;
}
.bubble-wrap {
    background-image: url(../images/water-drop-banner.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 43px;
    border-top-width: 3px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #03F;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.row {
    margin-top:20px;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.clear {
    clear:both
}
.example blockquote {
    background:#f9f9f9;
    border-left:10px solid #333;
    margin:1.5em 10px;
    padding:.5em 10px;
    blockquote {
        background:#f9f9f9;
        border-left:10px solid #ccc;
        margin:1.5em 10px;
        padding:.5em 10px;
        quotes:"201C""201D""2018""2019";
    }
}
.example blockquote:before {
    color:#333;
    content:open-quote;
    font-size:4em;
    line-height:.1em;
    margin-right:.25em;
    vertical-align:-.4em;
}
.example blockquote p {
    display:inline;
}
hr {
    width:75%;
}
ul.fa-ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height:1.2;
    font-size:36px;
}
i.fa-li.fa.fa-check-square-o.fa-2, i.fa-li.fa.fa-check-square-o.fa-4 {
    color:red;
    font-weight:500;
}
.green {
    color: #339933;
}
.address {
}
.greenhouse-attn {
    width:100%;
    padding-top:55px;
    padding-bottom:55px;
}
.greenhouse-list {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
/* 
    #contact {
     width: 300px;
     margin-top: 75px;
     margin-bottom: 50px;
     height: 200px;
     margin-left: 45px;
     float: left;
    }*/
 #contact-form {
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    margin-top: 0px;
    clear: both;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #333333;
}
footer.footer .row {
    margin-top:0;
}
#social-icons {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.feature-margin {
    margin-top:35px;
    margin-bottom:45px;
}
i.fa.fa-hand-o-right {
    color:blue;
    font-size:2rem;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-right:8px;
}
/* Portrait tablets and medium desktops */
 @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .col-md-7 h2.featurette-heading.align-right {
        text-align:initial;
    }
}
/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .col-md-7 h2.featurette-heading.align-right {
        text-align:initial;
    }
}
/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-md-7 h2.featurette-heading.align-right {
        text-align:initial;
    }
    .slogan {
        margin-top:0;
        float:none;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
}
/* Landscape phones and smaller */
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
    .col-md-7 h2.featurette-heading.align-right {
        text-align:initial;
    }
}
body {
    background-color: #C4C0BF;
    background-image:url(../images/background_light_slice.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x
}
.glow {
    background-image:url(../images/background_light.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#logo-box img {
    border:none;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.slogan {
    float:right;
    margin-top: 75px;
}
.starter-template {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #C4C0BF;
}
.float-right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
}
img {
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
}
.float-left {
    float: left;
}
.align-right {
    text-align:right;
}
.container-wrap {
}
.nav-wrap {
    border-top:1px solid #dedede;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dedede;
    background-color:#333333;
}
nav.navbar.navbar-default {
    background-color:#333333;
    border:none;
}
.navbar {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color:#efeeee;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #b8b6b6;
}
.bubble-wrap {
    background-image: url(../images/water-drop-banner.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 43px;
    border-top-width: 3px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #03F;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.row {
    margin-top:20px;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.clear {
    clear:both
}
.example blockquote {
    background:#f9f9f9;
    border-left:10px solid #333;
    margin:1.5em 10px;
    padding:.5em 10px;
    blockquote {
        background:#f9f9f9;
        border-left:10px solid #ccc;
        margin:1.5em 10px;
        padding:.5em 10px;
        quotes:"201C""201D""2018""2019";
    }
}
.example blockquote:before {
    color:#333;
    content:open-quote;
    font-size:4em;
    line-height:.1em;
    margin-right:.25em;
    vertical-align:-.4em;
}
.example blockquote p {
    display:inline;
}
hr {
    width:75%;
}
ul.fa-ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height:1.2;
    font-size:36px;
}
i.fa-li.fa.fa-check-square-o.fa-2, i.fa-li.fa.fa-check-square-o.fa-4 {
    color:red;
    font-weight:500;
}
.green {
    color: #339933;
}
.address {
}
.greenhouse-attn {
    width:100%;
    padding-top:55px;
    padding-bottom:55px;
}
.greenhouse-list {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
/* 
    #contact {
     width: 300px;
     margin-top: 75px;
     margin-bottom: 50px;
     height: 200px;
     margin-left: 45px;
     float: left;
    }*/
 #contact-form {
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    margin-top: 0px;
    clear: both;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #333333;
}
footer.footer .row {
    margin-top:0;
}
#social-icons {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.feature-margin {
    margin-top:35px;
    margin-bottom:45px;
}
i.fa.fa-hand-o-right {
    color:blue;
    font-size:2rem;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-right:8px;
}
/* Portrait tablets and medium desktops */
 @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .col-md-7 h2.featurette-heading.align-right {
        text-align:initial;
    }
}
/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
 @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .col-md-7 h2.featurette-heading.align-right {
        text-align:initial;
    }
}
/* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-md-7 h2.featurette-heading.align-right {
        text-align:initial;
    }
    .slogan {
        margin-top:0;
        float:none;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
}
/* Landscape phones and smaller */
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
    .col-md-7 h2.featurette-heading.align-right {
        text-align:initial;
    }
}

#mc_embed_signup{
    font-size:14px;
    color:#b8b6b6;
    margin-top:17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/slim-081711.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container glow img-responsive">
    <div id="logo-box"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/meridian-logo.png" width="363" height="184" class="float-left img-responsive"/></a>
        <div class="slogan">
            <img src="images/commercial-filtration-specialists.png" width="355" height="19" alt="Commercial &amp; Light Industrial Filtration Specialists" class="center-block" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="nav-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Meridian - Home</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="Abouiron-removal-system.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About &amp; Examples
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="iron-removal-system.html">Iron Removal System</a></li>
                                <li><a href="completed-system-photos.html">Completed System Photos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <!--end of dropdown menu -->
                        </li>
                        <!--end of dropdown list items -->
                        <li><a href="greenhouse-and-nursery.html">Greenhouse &amp; Nursery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="irrigation.html">Irrigation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="features.html">Features</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<!--end of container with header and nav -->
<div class="container-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <article>
                    <header>
                        <h1>Meridian Water Filtration: Irrigation & Residential water solutions</h1>
                    </header>
                    <p>Besides solutions for greenhouse and nursery water problems Meridian Water Filtration has irrigation and filtration available for:</p>
                    <p>These filtration systems will eliminate all of the problems related to iron such as staining. Often condo complexes, housing developments and golf courses experience trouble with staining on items like fencing, sinage or lawn furniture. Anything vinyl or plastic may be susceptible to such unsightly iron stains.</p>
                    <p>Your customers will notice beautiful property not water stains!</p>
                    <p>With Meridian Iron removal solutions we will help you make sure; they will view your property exactly how you intend them too!</p>
                </article>
            </div>
            <!--end of first col -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="images/golf-course-filtration.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Flowers in a greenhouse" class="img-responsive center-block" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <div class="greenhouse-attn">
                 <h3 class="center">Besides solutions for greenhouse and nursery water problems Meridian Water Filtration has irrigation and filtration available for:</h3>
                <div class="list-wrap">
                    <div class="greenhouse-list">
                        <ul class="fa-ul">
                            <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square-o fa-2" style="color:green"></i>Condominium complexes</li>
                            <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square-o fa-2" style="color:green"></i>Golf Courses</li>
                            <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square-o fa-2" style="color:green"></i>Agriculture</li>
                            <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square-o fa-2" style="color:green"></i>Residential irrigation</li>
                            <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square-o fa-2" style="color:green"></i>Residential sulfur removal</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="lead">
                    <br/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <!--end of row -->
</div>
<!--end of column container -->
<p></p>
<!--end of main container which contains the colmns and the quotes -->
<div class="bubble-wrap">
    <!--contains bubble ribbon -->
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="social-icons">
                    <a href="//plus.google.com/104130344147331418420?prsrc=3" target="_new" style="text-decoration:none;" rel="publisher">
                        <img src="//ssl.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-32.png" alt="Google+" style="border:0;width:32px;height:32px;"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div>
                    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
                        <form action="//meridianwaterfiltration.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=295abf2c8365b6eb68c704c9e&amp;id=3c6eb9409c" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                            <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                                <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to our mailing list</label>
                                <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required />
                                <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                                <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="b_295abf2c8365b6eb68c704c9e_3c6eb9409c" tabindex="-1" value="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End container-->
</footer>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will need to include enough code for a reproducible example *here in the question*, rather than linking to a site, otherwise this question risks being closed as Off-Topic.

Comment: I'm really grateful for the help, I will provide any code; where do I provide that?  I'm obviously new to Stack Overflow too... THANK YOU !

Comment: Add the code into the post itself. In the WYSIWYG editor, there will be a document icon with two brackets `< >` on it. Click that and it will open up an editor for you to paste your HTML, CSS, and include any framework/library dependencies like Bootstrap

Comment: I added some code for you let me know if you need anything else ;-)  I appreciate your patience while I learn more about how to use Stack Overflow...thank you!

Comment: It looks like you have an extra closing `</li> </ul>` in `div#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1`. Remove those two closing tags and see what that does. You'll also need to include your CSS as well, rather than just the links to the file.

Comment: Ok will do and then post back!  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Ok I removed those extra closing tags, and added the css file for you to see...
.  I also just noticed that the footer is not showing the correct color either.  (**I just wanted to mention again that these issues are only showing in IE 8)